# how to insert milions of values into vector without using for loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

i wanted to insert millions of records into vector is there any other technique than using for loop like from 0 to millions time insert record one by one...

Is there any faster method is available instead of inserting one by one element into vector????

Thank you,

Comment: At initialization? From disk?

Comment: whatever suppose i have int nos from o to 10000, i created a int vector so i wanted to inserted 0 to 10000 nos into vector without using for loop like traversing it from 0 to 10000 and insert one by one element....

Comment: If your program design requires a vector with millions of elements, it's probably a good idea to reconsider your design...

Comment: `std::iota`, `std::generate`?  They all boil down to a loop somewhere whether you write it yourself or not.

Comment: what should be the best practice in this scenario ?? should i used vector or something else for storing these nos?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain the entire issue you're trying to solve rather than this one particular thing.

Comment: if you want millions of the default constructed version of your record you can use `std::vector<Record> myvect(N);` where `N` is an integer that is millions.  Probably not quite what you are looking for though.

Comment: @T.C., there is absolutely nothing wrong with a vector with millions of elements. It is usually the best container for large in-memory collections.

Comment: You could write one million lines of code that add one element each.

Comment: @Don Reba. Depends on what you are trying to do. If whatever you are doing really requires having those millions of values in memory at the same time, sure. If you are processing a file with millions of lines one line at a time, reading the whole thing into the memory isn't a great idea.